# Unable to update records into mysql using inline editing in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, inline-editing

I am working on codeigniter inline editing using jquery ajax .
i am using the below code :

**In view -**

```
<script>


function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
} 


function save(editableObj,column,id) {

    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(<?php echo site_url('img/loaderIcon.gif');?>loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({

        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>student_master/getEditValues",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&iid='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }  

    });
}

</script>
```

**Controller -**

```
function getEditValues()
{
  $column = $this->input->post('column');
  $editval = $this->input->post('editval');
  $id = $this->input->post('id');
  $updtinfo = $this->studentspersonaldetails->inline($column, $editval, $id);

  return;
}
```

**Model -**

```
 public function inline($column, $editval, $id)
 {
     $result = mysql_query("UPDATE student_job_details set $column = $editval WHERE  stud_id=$id");
 }
```

I am stuck here that values is changed at DOM but not into database.
Please help me where i am wrong

Comment: is it returning 500 error in the debug console ?

Comment: What exactly happening when it goes to controller? Any error in console or something else please elaborate

Comment: Check your developer console to see what error you are getting

Comment: nothing is showing....!!

Comment: Change `mysql_query` to `$this->db->query("UPDATE... ")`